# Outlook (2010) puts unnecessary gap between image row

Tags: html, email, outlook

just want to ask, having a code like this:

```
<table border="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><a href="index.html" target="_blank"><img style="border: 0px none;" src="img/image.jpg" alt="" width="250" height="250" border="0" /></a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><a href="index.html" target="_blank"><img style="border: 0px none;" src="img/image.jpg" alt="" width="300" height="300" border="0" /></a></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

this should look like an image on the upper row, and another image on the lower one.
In outlook, those two rows are having a large gap in between and I don't know what's causing this.

This table is inside a td with another table.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

**HTML**

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="line-height:0; padding:0"><a href="index.html" target="_blank"><img style="border: 0px none; vertical-align:top" src="img/image.jpg" alt="" width="250" height="250" border="0" vspace="0" hspace="0" /></a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="line-height:0; padding:0"><a href="index.html" target="_blank"><img style="border: 0px none; vertical-align:top" src="img/image.jpg" alt="" width="300" height="300" border="0"  vspace="0" hspace="0" /></a></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Sorry. Cant to check. Please leave a feed is it help or not

Comment: I tried this, but unfortunately, it doesn't work. Thanks anyways.

Comment: @NicoMasuli Oh sorry didnt mentioned last time just add cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" to your table tag. And set the padding:0 to your <td>

Comment: Still doesn't work. 
I edited the question and added some more info.

Comment: @NicoMasuli You need to insert cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" in every table you have in the markup